# How to launch colorbox automatically without any click?

Tags: jquery, cakephp, colorbox

The purpose of my program is to open a colorbox with JQuery clicking on a link.

**Here's the code :**

```
<a href="<?= $html->url(array('controller' => 'competitions', 'action' => 'index')) ?>" class="game-popup">
    <?= $this->Html->image('image-link.jpg') ?>
</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.game-popup').colorbox({'iframe':true, 'width':'690px', 'height':'670px'});
});
</script>
```

*This code works perfectly.*

Now for an other reason I need to open a colorbox automatically with a special condition without any click. I tried with the code below but I can't access to my controller:

```
<a href="<?= $html->url(array('controller' => 'competitions', 'action' => 'index')) ?>" class="game-popup">
    <?= $this->Html->image('competition-galaxy-s3.jpg') ?>
</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.colorbox({'iframe':true, 'width':'690px', 'height':'670px'});
  document.location.href="/ArgusDuMobile/competitions/index";
});
</script>
```

The line of code with `$.colorbox` seems to be good because when I refresh the page the colorbox is being opened but without its content. To do the link with the controller I tried the following line of code with `document` but it open the correct content of the view in an other page but not into the colorbox.

Does anyone could help me? Thanks in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call colorbox with `href` option like

```
$.colorbox({ href: '/ArgusDuMobile/competitions/index',
            'iframe':true, 'width':'690px', 'height':'670px'});
```

and this line

```
document.location.href="/ArgusDuMobile/competitions/index";
```

Will redirect to that page wont load that into colorbox so remove that.

Read more on [`href`](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox) option.

Comment: thanks I found the solution in the same time. Have a good day. Bye